# ElasticSearch Wrapping Head on Index Types

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking into elastic search right now and I am having a hard time grasping how index types fit into the data model, I've read examples and documentation but none really goes in depth or the examples seem to use a data model that is composed of several submodels.

I am currently using mongodb to store my data, let's take this example of an Article collection that I want to be indexed for search, my doc looks like this:

```
Article = {
    title: String,
    publisher: String,
    subject: String,
    description: String,
    year: Integer,
}
```

Now I want each of those fields to be searchable, so I would make an elasticsearch index of 'Article'. I will need to define each field and how it should be analysed and whether it is stored or not, that I understand.

Now how does an index type come in here? As far as I am aware, Lucene does not have this concept, this is a layer added by Elasticsearch.

For example, maybe some of you may say that we can logically group the documents by subject  or publisher and create index types on those but how is this different from searching by subject or publisher?

Is it more of a performance related aspect that we have index types?

Answer (score 0):

Not a very easy question to answer, but I am going to give it a try. But be warned this just my opinion.

First of all, if you do not want to keep certain documents together in an index, just because it feels they should, create separate indices. There is not really a penalty for using more indices over more types. The only thing I can think of is that you could create analysers and mappings that you can reuse over the different types.

You can use types if you feel documents belong together, they have similar structure but not necessary the same structure. Be warned though, do not create separate mappings for fields with the same name in different types within the same index. Lucene does not like this.

Than there is the final scenario, in parent-child relationships, here you need types. This way the parent and it's children can be places in the same shard which is better for performance.

Hope that helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the catch with using more than one data type in one index is almost identical to using different indices. Say, you can store (as I did) documents of types "simple_address", "delivery_address", "some_strange_but_official_address_info" in the same index "address" to make your code a bit more sane. But if you don't use parent-child links, it's equivalent to just having three indices.

Speaking of your example, you should wrap your head around what would you like to search. If, for instance, you add comments in equation, it's better to use some kind of separation - either as parent-child or different indices with manual mapping by keys. And, obviously, you should have different mappings for "Article" and "Comment" types.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, having a parent child relationship defined as different types in a index, in my case I don't have such a relationship, so I am forced to do something like Articles/Article (Index/Type). I simply have entities.

Comment: @iQ so looks like you can use whatever setup you want; just beware scaling beyond "articles only"-mode.
And one more thing, having different indices means different multy-node setup issues.